# How can I insert a small rectangle inside the rectangle?

Tags: css, html

[image: I want to make something like this].

Here is my link http://jsfiddle.net/ashadee/xhaLqvav/.

Html code

```
<a href="#" class="rectangle">Eat your lunch</a><br>
```

CSS

```
a{
        font-size: 1.2em;
        white-space: normal;
    }
a.rectangle
{
    width: 70%;
    height: 5%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    opacity: 0.4;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Comic Sans MS;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```

how will I make the design like the one in the image? Should I use canvas property.

Comment: you could add a `div` and further elements within your `a`-element like `<a href="#"><div>...</div></a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/xhaLqvav/2/

use `pseudo` element `:after` and `:before` for styling right box and rounded

```css
a {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  white-space: normal;
}
a.rectangle {
  width: 70%;
  height: 5%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5%;
  margin-top: 0%;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  opacity: 0.4;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: Comic Sans MS;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
  position: relative;
}
a:before {
  content: '';
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: orange;
  width: 50px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
a:after {
  content: '';
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 35px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translatey(-50%)
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="rectangle">Stanford</a>
<br>
```

Comment: Worked like charm, thanks. You saved my day. I wish I could date u for the remaining time.. haha

Comment: Inside the circle to add that pencil type element. Will I have to use a <div> tag?

Comment: use a background-image for pseudo element `:after`